# How can I use EF Core without appsettings.json

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I need to use the `dotnet ef tools utility`, but I need to set a connection string in `appsettings.json`.
I don't want to store it in `appsettings.json`, because project is stored in the git repository.
At the moment, I keep `launchSettings.json` in the `EnvironmentVariables` section, but this does not help me because `dotnet ef tools` simply does not see these values. I tried to implement `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory` but everything is the same. He just doesn't see these values.
I found a solution that requires you to explicitly enter the value of the connection string, but this option also does not work.

Comment: One way is to use `appsettings.Development.json` in combination with a `.gitignore` rule to exclude that file from being sent to git. Note: add the rule & save it, before you accidentally add the file to git.

Comment: Another solution is to pass a connection string in with the `dotnet ef` tools commands as an argument and use `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory.Create...` which will take that connection string in it's `String[] args` parameter. According to the docs. This requires 5.0 or later. Previous versions did not use that paramter.

Answer (score 1):

The thing is that you should not store any secret value in git/repository at all.

Ideally this connnection string should be in a vault/Secret place which you will have access using another password, so eventually you need to "store" a password somewhere.

There is differnt approaches for this, as mention the most common one will be something like `_secret.GetConnectionString()` -> this calls to another service which will return the connectionstring.

Other solution you can do (probably better in your case) is to "setup" a default/plain `appsettings.json` just store the value like `connection: xxxxxx` and then use environment variables to replace that value. The configuration builder is already built with this in mind.

```
var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
  .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
  .AddEnvironmentVariables() //This line here
  .Build();
```

Then you can just set up the value in your own machine.

For deploying to production it will depends which software you use to deploy the app, but it will have some way to allow you to add environment variables.

Finally, as an extension of the previous code you can add your "own" `json`

```
var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
  .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
  .AddJsonFile("appsettings.private.json")
  .Build();
```

So doing this, in `appsettings.private.json` you will only need to write the connectionstring property. You will not need to write the entire document.

and then you can just add a rule on .gitignore to ignore it.